# Java code which tracks news on a website, and saves some specific information on the instance that the news is posted

Tags: java

I'm a complete greenhorn to programming. I've been watching and performing tutorials for the last few days, but I have a little project I'd like to get to asap.

I'd like to keep track of a news website. Imagine a phone app running on a loop once every minute, few minutes, or so. The loop is responsible for tracking news on cnn.com. Once a new article pops up, the application stores a few data points related to it. For example, name, date stamp, maybe a direct link to it?

Is Jsoup the way to go here?

Comment: That is called as RSS feed.

Comment: That might be just what I was looking for, many thanks!